# How can i use the param id in params_permit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i put the id inside of my params?

so far i am doing like this:

```
def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:name, :country, user_id:params[:user_id], live_id: live.id)
end
```

I want to put params[:user_id] and live.id inside of params

Answer (score 0):

You can set live id from your controller actions instead of using param method. Please follow below steps. Hope it will be useful for you.

```
def create
  live = Live.create()
  
  # Set live id inside post_params
  @post = Post.new(post_params.merge!(live_id: live.id))

  # If you have current_user present you can set user_id as well using below way
  # @post = Post.new(post_params.merge!(user_id: current_user.id, live_id: live.id))
   

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully 
                                           created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: 
                   @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: 
                     :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :country, :user_id, :live_id)
 end
```

Comment: this is neesesary still , :user_id, :live_id)? in params.require(:post).permit(:name, :country, :user_id, :live_id)